# Ionic datepicker min & max don't work on month & day

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to use ionic 2 datepicker, it works but when I want to use min & max properties it doesn't work.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"  [min]="event.date.today" [(ngModel)]="event.date.start"></ion-datetime>
```

It filter date only on years ! But I would like to have custom day and month.

```
'date': {
    'today': moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

[image]

Can you help me ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see from their source, ion-datetime only supports year. (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/datetime/datetime.ts)
Because the columns aren't dynamically changed based on the value. Rather picker is generated from the min/max.

I suggest you change your datetime columns manually to have full control.

Mark your html datetime

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"  #dateTime [(ngModel)]="event.date.start"></ion-datetime>
```

On set of the viewchild change its columns to have

```
@ViewChild('dateTime') public set dateTime(val: DateTime) {
    (<any>val.pickerOptions).columns[0].options = (<any>val.pickerOptions).columns[0].options.filter(year => year.value >= this.event.date.today.getFullYear());
    (<any>val.pickerOptions).columns[1].options = (<any>val.pickerOptions).columns[1].options.filter(month => month.value >= this.event.date.today.getMonth() + 1);
    (<any>val.pickerOptions).columns[2].options = (<any>val.pickerOptions).columns[2].options.filter(day => day.value >= this.event.date.today.getDate());
}
```

This will give you a datetime that will only have the years/months/days above or equal to specified.
Which means if you input 06/06/2016 as minimum then 01/07/201

If this doesn't satisify you,  you should search for a calendar component that would be more useful for this task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm using the native datepicker now, it works fine, but I have to debugg on simulator or device.

Thanks !